# Combine multiple where conditions having optional parameters in C# linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am searching for a LINQ query where I have 3 parameters and two are optional parameters for this I wrote if-else conditions like below

```
if (id != null) { where condition} 
else if (name!= null) { where condition } 
else if (category != null) { where condition } 
else if (id != null && name != null) { where condition } 
else if (id != null && category != null) { where condition } 
else if (name != null && category != null) {where condition} 
else if (id != null && name != null && category != null ) { where condition }
```

I don't want to write more if-else conditions if there is another optional parameter added

**Note**. Id is not a primary key

Comment: That’s.. valid?!?

Comment: Anyway, I think you might be looking for something like Where(x => (q == null || x.q == q) && ..) ; that is, the guards are moved INSIDE the filter. Otherwise CHAIN filters: f = ..; if (q != null) { f = f.Where(x => x.q == q); }

Comment: Being optional parameters is itself irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

The optimal pattern for this in EF is to add the Where conditions only conditionally.  EG

```
IQueryable<SomeType> qry = ...;
if (id != null)
{
  qry = qry.Where(x => x.Id == id);
}
if (name != null)
{
  qry = qry.Where(x => x.Name == name);
}
if (category != null)
{
  qry = qry.Where(x => x.Category == category);
}
var results = qry.ToList();
```

That way you don't clutter up the expression with lots of predicates that don't do anything, but which can mess up the query execution.

Answer (score 1):

What I always do is below. Easy to read and remember.

```
myList
    .Where(x => id == null || x.Id == id)
    .Where(x => name == null || x.Name == name)
    .Where(x => category == null || x.Category == category);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this

```
id == null ? true : {id condition} &&
name == null ? true : {name condition} &&
category == null ? true: {category } and other conditions
```

Or

```
id == null || {id condition} &&
id == null || {id condition} &&
```

returning true will make the statement true if its value equals null.
its clean, Easy to understand and develop.

I hope it helps.