# Ternary If in LINQ Query C#

Tags: c#, linq

Hi guys i have this code:

```
var sites = context.SITES.OrderBy(s => s.NAME).ToList();
 if (userId != 0)
     sites = context.SITES.OrderBy(s => s.NAME).Where(s => s.Users.Any(x => x.ID == userId)).ToList();
```

Is it possible to make the if inside the query? I need to do this code in one line

```
var sites = context.SITES.OrderBy(s => s.NAME) 
if(userId != 0) {
    .Where(s => s.Users.Any(x => x.ID == userId)) 
}
.ToList();
```

I want something like this

Comment: Don't make the if in the query. But don't use ToList before you don't know the final query, that will execute it. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727506/combine-multiple-where-conditions-having-optional-parameters-in-c-sharp-linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a slight modification to get it to work:

```
IQueryable<Site> sites = context.SITES.OrderBy(s => s.NAME) 
if(userId != 0) {
    sites = sites.Where(s => s.Users.Any(x => x.ID == userId)) 
}
```

Or you could inline the `if` this way:

```
var sites = sites.Where(s => (userId == 0) || (s.Users.Any(x => x.ID == userId))) 
                 .OrderBy(s => s.NAME)
                 .ToList()
```

Comment: Your first code block wouldn't compile though. (Something like "Cannot implicitly convert type IQueryable<Foo> to IOrderedQueryable<Foo>...")

Comment: Note also the second block, while it works, it is potentially sending an unnecessary bit of query to the database.

Comment: @stefano: but the first approach is clearly better even if i think you were asking for the second. The 2nd "pollutes" the query with  unnecessary conditions and you rely on the database that it's able to clean it up. If you are unlucky you  get a slower execution plan for no reason. So the optimal way is to use if's but without ToList every time

Comment: FWIW I use that pattern in parameterized queries all the time (`WHERE @x IS NULL or x=@x`) and generally don't find that it hurts performance, but it's a fair point.  Also removed the `var` to avoid the type error.

Comment: That's better, though I still dislike the second option. To me it feels a little lazy and I find harder to read..

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the ['deferred execution'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution) nature of `IQueryable`/Entity Framework here. So start with your initial query:

```
IQueryable<Site> query = context.SITES;
```

Now add a filter if needed:

```
if(userId != 0) {
    query = query.Where(s => s.Users.Any(x => x.ID == userId)) ;
}
```

Finally, add in the ordering and enumerate the result with the ToList:

```
var list = query.OrderBy(s => s.NAME).ToList();
```